# Date format not working in MVC with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to get some data to format in the ShortDateTime format of "MM/dd/yyyy" but everything I'm trying is not working.

I have the following EF below and the field I'm specifically looking at is the ExpireDate. When I try to use a DateTime.Parse around the field I get an error `cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?" to 'string'`. Without the DateTime.Parse then the date displays as `3/15/2017 12:00:00 AM`.

I tried using Data Annotations on the Model as well but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions?

EF query

```
data = (from e in ctx.clock_emp_excep_hist
        join g in ctx.clock_group on e.group_id equals g.group_id
        join emp in ctx.employee on e.emp_id equals emp.emp_id
        where e.group_id == 4
        select new 
        {
            UpdateDate = e.create_date,
            UpdateType = e.add_delete_ind,
            GroupId = e.group_id,
            GroupName = g.group_name,
            Reason = e.reason,
            ExpireDate = e.expiration_date,
            UpdateEmployeeId = e.emp_id,
            UpdateFirstName = emp.emp_firstname,
            UpdateLastName = emp.emp_lastname
        }).Select(e => new EmployeeExceptionLog {
                    UpdateDate = e.UpdateDate,
                    UpdateType = e.UpdateType == "A" ? "Add" : "Delete",
                    GroupId = e.GroupId,
                    GroupName = e.GroupName,
                    Reason = e.Reason,
                    ExpireDate = DateTime.Parse(e.ExpireDate),
                    UpdateEmployeeId = e.UpdateEmployeeId,
                    UpdateFirstName = e.UpdateFirstName,
                    UpdateLastName = e.UpdateLastName
        }).ToList();
    }
```

Property in class

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
public DateTime? ExpireDate { get; set; }
```

**More info:**

This is how I'm displaying the data in the View.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AuditLogs)
{
    <tr class="@(item.UpdateType == "Delete" ? "danger" : "")">
        <td>@item.UpdateDate</td>
        <td>@item.UpdateType</td>
        <td>@item.Reason</td>
        <td>@item.ExpireDate</td>
        <td>@item.UpdateEmployeeId - @item.UpdateFirstName @item.UpdateLastName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

The DataType in the Oracle Database is DateTime?.

Comment: In linq you need the methods to be implemented. Usually Convert.xxx  will work. I have not tested it, but I would try Convert.ToString

Comment: Are you storing dates in your database as strings?

Comment: DateTime has no format **at all**. It's a binary value. DateTime values get formatted when converted to strings, ie in your view.

Comment: How do you display these values? Please post your *view* code. If you use a simple `ToString()` or a helper that doesn't care about `DisplayFormat`, the attribute won't have any effect. On the other hand, *why* use an attribute set two layers below the view itself? Why not set the format in the helper itself, where you know how you want to display your value?

Comment: More info added to the original post.

Comment: you need to use htmlhelpers to get the date format annotations to work.  @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.UpdateDate).  @item.UpdateDate will display the raw value for the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public DateTime? ExpireDate { get; set; }
```

Its [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx) date so you can have Null value for ExpireDate.

```
"cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?" to 'string'"
ExpireDate = DateTime.Parse(e.ExpireDate),
```

[DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) takes string as a parameter.

i would change this to

```
ExpireDate = ((e.ExpireDate != null) ? (DateTime)e.ExpireDate : "SOME DEFAULT DATE"),
```

Also in View you can display using ToShortDateString() if your model property is dateTime.

```
<td>@item.ExpireDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
```

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) is more info about DateTime.

Comment: used DateTime.MinValue as the "SOME DEFAULT DATE" and then I had to do a conditional check in the View to see if the value.ToShortDateString() != "1/1/0001" then write out the date. That part isn't pretty but at least it works.

Comment: if your model property is DateTime? then you can check ExpireDate.Hasvalue ? ExpireDate.ToshortDateString() : "";

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse nullable DateTime.
To convert nullable DateTime into a formatted string :

```
ExpireDate != null ? ExpireDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "ERROR";
```

Update your query into this:

```
data = (from e in ctx.clock_emp_excep_hist
        join g in ctx.clock_group on e.group_id equals g.group_id
        join emp in ctx.employee on e.emp_id equals emp.emp_id
        where e.group_id == 4
        select new 
        {
            UpdateDate = e.create_date,
            UpdateType = e.add_delete_ind,
            GroupId = e.group_id,
            GroupName = g.group_name,
            Reason = e.reason,
            ExpireDate = e.expiration_date,
            UpdateEmployeeId = e.emp_id,
            UpdateFirstName = emp.emp_firstname,
            UpdateLastName = emp.emp_lastname
        }).Select(e => new EmployeeExceptionLog {
                    UpdateDate = e.UpdateDate,
                    UpdateType = e.UpdateType == "A" ? "Add" : "Delete",
                    GroupId = e.GroupId,
                    GroupName = e.GroupName,
                    Reason = e.Reason,
                    ExpireDate = ExpireDate != null ? ExpireDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "ERROR",
                    UpdateEmployeeId = e.UpdateEmployeeId,
                    UpdateFirstName = e.UpdateFirstName,
                    UpdateLastName = e.UpdateLastName
        }).ToList();
    }
```